# How to use dynamic field type in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to design a little on-line store. The website should have every detail about products. Since I am beginner I stuck at designing good database design.
There are many different products: Cellphone, Laptop, Stove, Bag, etc. Each of these products need different details. I am not going to design many different table for each, So one table (product) going to have all products.
But How I manage details? I couldn't find good topic on Google so I started my own poor design. This is my draft design:opps can not post image

- Product stores product name.
- Product_category defines type of product, like: mobile or book. each  product belongs to one product category
- Product_category_detail stores product attributes like color, wight,
  battery life etc. each product_category_details belongs to one
  product_category.
- Product_detail keeps values of detail like 3 hour
  for battery life, or 400g for wight. each of this belogns to one
  product category detail and product.

I can store all details in Var-char.
Is it good? any suggestion!
It's better to have type of detail. like varchar for color and int for wight.
I am thinking on another field in product_catefory_datail named attr_type so I can change convert in php.
Any idea? tnx

Comment: you can use `varchar` for  long fields. What ever the size you given in varchar, it only utilise the size of provoded data. So no wastage will occur. and for numbers, you can use int or bigint according to your need.

Comment: If you don't have many specialisations, consider using [table inheritance](http://propelorm.org/Propel/documentation/09-inheritance.html). (You don't have to use an ORM - the Propel docs just have a good description of the different approaches to the problem).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had this similar issue while doing a project, and developed tables which solved my problem . Hope this helps you too.

### product_table

```
pt_id,name,category
```

### product_category_table

```
pct_id,name,desc
```

### detail_fields

```
pf_id,field_name
```

### product_detail_fields

```
pdf_id,pt_id,pf_id,default_value
```

### product_detail_fields_values

```
pdfv_id,pdf_id,value,user_id  //here pdf_id is fk of product_detail_fields
```

If you have multiple users, make use of `user_id`, else ignore it.

Comment: There is no `pdf_id` in `product_details_fields`

Comment: @Justinas - I havnt given a full fledged database, the `product_detail_fields` table has an `id` in it. I have used that id as `pdf_id` in the next table for understanding purpose. Once you get the idea create your table based on the MOCK ups that i have presented. That was the idea. Is that why u voted me down ??

Comment: Yes, your table columns are not informative, there is no need for prefix for columns names. `SELECT pdf.pdf_id FROM product_details_fields pdf`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use `product` table only to keep generic information about product, than have `product_attributes` table:

```
ID (INT|Unique) | product_id (INT) | name (VARCHAR) | value (VARCHAR) | type (INT: predefined constant values)
```

Comment: I would support this answer. You could then create another table, which stores the attribute types for a certain product group.

Answer (score 0):

This is where you do need the [Entity Attribute Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) (EAV) model. If you need different data types then you need additional columns to specify the data type and for each data type: eg type specified as 'string' so select the string_value column, 'number' select the numeric_value column. That means CASE statemenst everywhere. Makes the whole thing horrible to work with.

Answer (score 0):

an online store is very complex, and not really a beginners task. It wont be scalable and since you dont know yet how many variations you need you'll end up with adding new tables and columns until it gets too complex.   Stores usually have a EAV model for this; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model .